# Active session in Lightning component

Tags: lightning, session

How can I check in my lightning component if a session is valid? Can I do this using only my javascript controller on the doInit or do I need to code in my apex controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [UserInfo Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) you should use UserInfo.getSessionId() and can validate using the [Session Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Session.htm) in your server side controller to validate if a user has an active session.

As far as I am concerned, you can only achieve this within an apex controller.